# Widget not working aws glue jupyter notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

I tried below code in aws glue jupyter notebook for widget textbox but I got text context but I expected text box.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
    from IPython.display import display
     
    text_input = widgets.Text(
        value='',
        placeholder='Enter some text',
        description='Text:',
        disabled=False
    )
    
     
    dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'],
        value='Option 1',
        description='Select an option:',
        disabled=False
    )
    
     
    display(text_input)
    display(dropdown)
```

Current Output:

> Text(value='', description='Text:', placeholder='Enter some text')
> Dropdown(description='Select an option:', options=('Option 1', 'Option
> 2', 'Option 3'), value='Option 1')

Expected Output:

I expected text box and dropdown box like data bricks. Please confirm we can able to achieve in aws glue jupyter notebook.